# Troubles with Aerospike 3.8.x monitored with monit on CentOS 7

Tags: shell, centos7, systemd, monit, aerospike

Since Aerospike went 3.8.0+, it changed the way the process ASD is launched. There is no more `/etc/init.d/aerospike` instead `systemd` is now used.

I have a problem as I use `monit` as a watchdog for aerospike and it is quite difficult to start / stop the asd process through systemd called by monit. Monit uses a limited path so maybe the problem comes from missing environment vars.

Here is what I use in monit:

```
check process aerospike with pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
start = "/usr/bin/bash -c '/opt/aerospike/aerospike-service.sh start'"
stop = "/usr/bin/bash -c '/opt/aerospike/aerospike-service.sh stop'"
```

I'm calling explicitely a shell script so that I can add environment vars on startup.

Here is my basic shell script:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
case "$1" in
start)
    echo "Starting aerospike Server ..."
    systemctl start aerospike.service
;;
stop)
    echo "Stopping aerospike Server ..."
    systemctl stop aerospike.service
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
exit 1
esac
```

I blindly copy-pasted my path at the start of the script. The script works if it is launched through CLI, but not if launched through monit.
I use CentOS 7.

I have not found a raw command to launch the asd process (and stop it) as it could be a way to not use systemd and sidestepping this problem.

Is there a way to configure monit to launch nicely systemd services, or are there raw commands for aerospike that can be used directly through monit?

Comment: Did you try just using `systemctl` in your monit commands, without the middleman shell script?

Comment: @XiongChiamiov yes, it fails too. I don't know what systemctl requires or the asd process requires that I miss.

Comment: This may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-system-d-service

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the monit and systemd logs?